# Flutter Desktop Podfile Missing (flutter run -d macOS)

Tags: macos, flutter, flutter-dependencies, podfile, flutter-desktop

flutter run -d macOS

```
Downloading darwin-x64 tools...                                   107.0s
Downloading darwin-x64-profile tools...                            69.7s
Downloading darwin-x64-profile tools...                            23.6s
Downloading darwin-x64-release tools...                            54.3s
Downloading darwin-x64-release tools...                            20.4s
```

Launching lib/main.dart on macOS in debug mode...
Podfile missing

When i run `flutter run -d macOS` code it showing Podfile missing and how to fix it?
Mac Pro
How to run mac desktop app using android studio?
If it is not possible to run macOS app from android studio then which ide i need to use?

Comment: is there a directory named `macOS` in your project?

Comment: no,there is no folder with name macOS

Comment: try this:
`flutter config --enable-macos-desktop`
and then in your project root:
`flutter create .`

Comment: Also you have to be in the `master` channel.

Comment: I all ready run flutter config --enable-macos-desktop and it is not a new project it is an old project for android app

Comment: yes even if it is an old project, `flutter create .` in the root of your project will create the `macOS` folder needed to run it on mac. Don't worry it wont touch your existing files. Also remember to run it in flutter project root and not in `android` folder.

Comment: Ok, i wil try with this suggestions

Comment: you can read more [here](https://flutter.dev/desktop#add-desktop-support-to-an-existing-flutter-project)

Answer (score 5):

The `Podfile missing` message may also appear when you have selected the command-line tools. In that case it can be fixed with

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

That fixed it for me when I switched to Flutter 2.0.
I also ran `flutter create --platforms=macos .` before, but that didn't fix it.

Comment: This fixed it for me. Is there anything else I should be aware of when doing this? Is this change likely to break other things?

Comment: No idea, never used XCode for anything but as a compiler for flutter 

Answer (score -2):

Add desktop support to an existing Flutter project
To add desktop support to an existing project, run the following command in a terminal from the root project directory:

flutter create .

To run your project as a desktop app, use the following command:

flutter run -d macOS

[for more](https://flutter.dev/desktop#add-desktop-support-to-an-existing-flutter-project)